# django count number of records with the same related record

Tags: python, django, orm, annotations

I am using django 1.5.5 with Mysql

I have this models

```
class Student(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique = True)

class Score(models.Model)
     student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
     date = models.DateTimeField()
     score = models.IntegerField()
```

i want to get all the score **records** that have a score of 0 and there is another 0 for the same student.

What i have tried:

```
scores = Score.objects.annotate(score_count = Count('student__id')).filter(score = 0 , score_count__gt = 1)
```

another thing i tried this one i think does get me what i need but it takes 2 queries.

```
students = Score.objects.filter(score = 0).values('student__id').annotate(c=Count('student__id')).filter(c__gt=1).values_list('student__id',flat=True)
score = Score.objects.filter(score = 0 , student__id__in = students)
```

any way to do it in one query ?

Comment: `Score.objects.values('student__id').filter(score=0).annotate(c=Count('score')).filter(c__gt=1)` ??

Comment: @AamirAdnan this will only give me the values and not the score records.

Answer (score 0):

```
no_of_records = len(Score.objects.values('student__id').filter(score=0).annotate(c=Count('score')‌​).f‌​ilter(c__gt=1))
```

OR

```
no_of_records = len(Score.objects.values('student__id').filter(score=0).annotate(c=Count('score')‌​).f‌​ilter(c__gt=1)).count()
```